# Can UIScrollView clipsToBounds be applied vertically only?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

When I set UIScrollView clipsToBounds property to NO, it allowed me to display the content views horizontally outside its bound.  That is what I wanted to achieve. But it also allowed to scroll pass top and bottom bounds which I do not want.

Can UIScrollView clipsToBounds be applied vertically only?

(btw: I want to effect just as in the picture so I do not want to expand the content view horizontally.)

[image]

Comment: Why do you want it to draw outside its bounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution would be to embed scroll view inside another view, which would have `clipToBounds = NO`, while scroll view would have `clipToBounds = YES` and width equal to content beign displayed.

As I am not good with images, I try example by code:

```
wrapperView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300);
wrapperView.clipToBounds = NO;

scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 300);
scrollView.clipToBounds = YES
[wrapperView addSubview:scrollView];

contentView.frame= CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 1234); 
[scrollView addSubview:contentView];
```